# Filter Elastic aggregation result in which several field have null value

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't filter from the elastic response several subjects/buckets in which two fields have a 'null' value.

I was writing something like:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "username.d": [
                  "abc.com"
                ],
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "authorization_service.d": [
                  "gmail.com"
                ],
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "username.email"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "username.login"
              }
            }
          ],
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "password.hash",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

and will get something like:

```
"aggregations": { - 
    "subjects": { - 
      "after_key": { - 
        "subject": null,
        "login": null,
        "authorization_service": "abc.com"
      },
      "buckets": [ - 
        { - 
          "key": { - 
            "subject": null,
            "login": null,
            "authorization_service": "abc.com"
          },
          "doc_count": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

So, it looks like I can find subjects/buckets in which I have **"subject": null** and **"login": null**, however, I need to filter out such cases. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: This construction 
`"must_not" with exists`
helps to find cases where 
"subject": null,
"login": null

However, I don't need to look for such cases, I want to remove them from the overall answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky to suggest something without example docs and the full query but I would try to use a filter clause with exists.

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "user.login"
          }
        }
      ]....
    }
  },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach will not work. Since I need to remove from the general case only those cases where "subject" will be null AND "login" will be null also.